# Running pytest.main in python code always returns value of None when argument is clearly set

Tags: python, pytest, conftest

This is the test file that i am running.

```
# this file is test_define.py

import pytest

def test_it(aw_name):
    print(aw_name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(['-s', 'v', '--aw_name', 'boom', 'test_define.py'])
```

This is the conftest file in the same directory

```
# conftest file
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--aw_name", action="store")

@pytest.fixture
def aw_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption("aw_name")
```

Running this in terminal works properly and prints out:

```
% pytest -s -v --aw_name boom test_define.py
```

But when I run in pycharm using the play button for the "if **name** == '**main**':" I always get a value of None. Am i missing something in the pytest.main call? I've also double checked that the interpreter is set to the same as the terminal.

Comment: Your test expects a variable called `aw_name`, but you're passing it an argument called `--name`.

Comment: @physicalattraction sorry my mistake. Typo on my end. But even when the parameter is set to "--aw_name" I still get a printed value of None when the test runs

Comment: Where are your test files located? Is your purest play-button call for sure calling pytest from the same working directory as when you call purest from the terminal?

Comment: @BLimitless test file is located in the same directory as the conftest file and a __init__.py file. The interpreter in PyCharm is set properly since im using a virtual env. keep in mind when im running in terminal I have the same venv activated